# Need help with a continuity proof

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f:R$ to $R$ be continuous on $R$, and let P:= {$x∈R: f(x)>0$}. If $c∈P$, show that there exists a neighbourhood $V_δ(c)⊆P$

Can I say: Let $ε>0$ be given, there exists $δ>0$ such that if$|x−c|<δ$, then$|f(x)−f(c)|<ε$. So let $ε:=f(c)>0$. Then there exists $δ(f(c))>0$ such that for all $|x−c|<δ(f(c)),|f(x)−f(c)|<ε⇐⇒−f(c)<f(x)-f(c)<f(c) =⇒ 0<f(x).$ Since $c∈P$, then $V_δ(c)⊆P$.

Comment: Yes the arguements are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is correct, so yes you can say that.